# C++11: Expression Templates VS RValue References

Tags: c++, c++11

Доброго времени суток!

В процессе размышлений над новыми возможностями привнесенными в стандарт языка С++, в частности rvalue-ссылками у меня возник вот какой вопрос. 
Насколько я понял, rvalue-ссылки позволяют оптимизировать возвращаемое значение, т.е. вместо копирования памяти происходит *перемещение*  объекта в памяти (из одной области в другую). До нового стандарта, насколько мне известно, данная проблема решалась через expression templates, означает ли что применяя rvalue-ссылки можно забыть об expression templates? Или я что-то неверно понимаю?

**UPDATE:** Уточню вопрос. Предположим у нас есть класс вида:

```
namespace math {
template<typename T>
class vector
{
public:
   vector() : mptr(0), msize(0) {
   }
   vector(size_t n) : msize(n) {
        mptr = new T[n];
   }
   vector(const vector& other) : msize(other.msize) {
        if (mptr) delete[] m_ptr;
        if (msize == 0) {
            mptr = 0;
        } else {
            mptr = new T[msize];
            std::copy(other.mptr, other.mptr + msize, m_ptr);
        }
   }
   ~vector() {
       if (mptr)
          delete[] mptr;
   }

   vector& operator=(const vector& other) {
            msize = other.msize;
        if (mptr) delete[] m_ptr;
        if (msize == 0) {
            mptr = 0;
        } else {
            mptr = new T[msize];
            std::copy(other.mptr, other.mptr + msize, m_ptr);
        }
   }
   vector& operator+=(const vector& x) {
        assert(x.size() == msize)
        std::transform(x.m_ptr, x.mptr+msize, mptr, std::plus<T>());
   }
   vector& operator-=(const vector& x) {
        assert(x.size() == msize)
        std::transform(x.m_ptr, x.mptr+msize, mptr, std::plus<T>());
   }
   // ... и так далее
private:
   T* mptr;
   size_t msize;
};
} // end namespace math
```

Теперь предположим мы хотим перегрузить *бинарные* операторы (+,-, и т.д.) :

```
template<typename T>
vector<T> operator+ (const vector<T>& x, const vector<T>& y)
{
    vector<T> res(x); // временная переменная - копия x
    res += y; // складываем x+y
    return res; // возвращаем результат
}
```

Теперь мы воспользуемся нашим классом:

```
math::vector<double> a(1 << 18);
math::vector<double> b(1 << 18);
math::vector<double> c(1 << 18);
math::vector<double> d(1 << 18);

math::vector<double> r = a * b - c + d;
```

При выполнении этого кода будет создано как минимум 3 временных массива размера 2^18, в каждом операторе, которых можно избежать. Собственно это будет приводить к снижению производительности. Раньше это обходилось с помощью expression templates, которые разворачивали выражение a * b - c + d в один цикл следующим образом:

math::vector<double> r(n);
for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    r[i] = a[i]* b[i] - c[i] + d[i];

В новом С++11 мы добавим к нашему классу конструктор перемещения и оператор перемещения (если я их правильно назвал), и объявление нашего класса поменяется следующим образом:

```
namespace math {
    template<typename T>
    class vector
    {
    public:
       vector();
       vector(size_t n);
       vector(const vector&);
       // Перемещающий кострктор
       vector(const vector&& other);
       vector& operator=(const vector&);
       // Перемещающий оператор присваивания
       vector& operator=(const vector&&);
       // ...
    };
 }
```

Значит ли это, что теперь мы избавлены от копий и можем забыть про expression templates?
Не об этом ли речь в http://www.artima.com/cppsource/rvalue.html в разделе 'Eliminating spurious copies'?

P.S. Код писал без проверки - только чтобы показать идеи, так что за ошибки не пинайте :)

Заранее спасибо за ответы!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Хм. Насколько я понимаю, смысл rvalue-ссылок в том, что перемещения данных *не происходит*. То есть, данные, которыми пользовался объект, можно «присвоить» себе без копирования, т. к. объект всё равно собирается исчезнуть.

Статья по теме rvalue references: http://www.artima.com/cppsource/rvalue.html (Бьярн среди авторов).

---

Обновление:

Я не встречался с expression template'ами раньше. Если они и правда делают то, о чём вы говорите, то rvalue references слабее, и не являются адекватной заменой.

Смотрите. Если у вас есть код

```
math::vector<double> r = a * b - c * d + e;
```

(я специально сделал умножение из сложения) и нужные move-конструкторы, что произойдёт? Этот код будет проинтерпретирован как

```
math::vector<double>&& tmp1 = a * b;
math::vector<double>&& tmp2 = c * d;
math::vector<double>&& tmp3 = tmp1 - tmp2;
math::vector<double> r = tmp3 + e;
```

Будет вызван дважды `operator * (const math::vector& l, const math::vector& r)`, который обязан выделять **новую** память, т. к. не может отобрать её у операндов. Затем будет вызван `operator - (const math::vector& l, const math::vector& r)`, который так же не сможет отобрать память у операндов. Далее, будет вызван `operator + (const math::vector& l, const math::vector& r)` с той же проблемой. Финальное присваивание обычно убирается оптимизатором ([RVO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization)). Move-конструкторы **вовсе не вступают в игру**, за исключением может быть того, что они подменяют RVO.

Что могла бы здесь улучшить move-семантика? С умножениями ничего улучшить нельзя: им по факту неоткуда брать память, придётся выделять новую всё равно. С вычитанием немного лучше: если вы определите перегрузку `operator -`, принимающую rvalue ref как первый аргумент, то вы сможете отобрать у него память. Для симметрии вам нужно будет сделать *ещё одну* перегрузку, принимающую rvalue ref как *второй* аргумент. И судя по всему ещё одну с двумя rvalue ref-аргументами, иначе компилятор не сможет выбрать между предыдущими двумя, если оба аргумента — rvalue ref. То же касается и сложения.

Обратите внимание, что вам нужен достаточно серьёзный дубляж кода: *все* операторы должны быть объявлены по 3, а то и 4 раза.

Таким образом, мы имеем два выделения памяти и два отбора памяти у rvalue-объектов. Это лучше, чем без move-семантики, но expression templates, как вы их описали, ещё лучше: там лишнее выделение памяти вовсе не требуется.

Вывод: нет, rvalue reference'ы всё ещё не панацея.

Comment: именно так, присвоение памяти без копирования)

Comment: Я обновил вопрос. Взгляните если не лень))

Comment: @progzdeveloper: Обновил ответ.

Comment: А компилятор не сможет определить, что переменные больше не используются и воспользоваться ими как rvalue-ссылками? А ещё я понятия не имею, как создать expression template...

Comment: @Qwertiy: Ну, это если переменные и правда больше не используются, раз. И если он такой умный, что сможет доказать, что деструктор равносилен move-перемещению в другой объект, два, и его можно выполнять не в конце блока, а внутри выражения, не меняя видимого поведения программы, три. Так что я ставлю на «нет».

Comment: @VladD, но ведь в деструктор только память освобождает? Та же штука, что для хвостовой рекурсии не прокатит, чтобы определить, что он не страшный? Кстати, move же не отменяет деструктор. Неужели в стандарте нет подходящего UB, что компилятор может что-то такое вытворить и нефиг городить разную логику для rvalue и нормальных переменных?)))

Comment: @Qwertiy: Ну, деструктор может и на консоль писать, кто ж ему запретит?

Comment: @Qwertiy: А `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` и `e` формально говоря не rvalue, а нормальные переменные вроде бы. И должны быть по стандарту уничтожены в конце блока. То есть перестановки возможны только если компилятор увидит в коде конструкторов, что реально от перестановки observable behaviour не изменится.